# Getting null when fetching ImageView from an item of and adapter. Why?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-imageview

I fetched texts, added to the ListView, then fetched images but getting null when trying to get the ImageView from the item inside the adapter to set the image. What am I doing wrong?

```
//AsyncTask For Texts.
private class pgData extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONArray> {

//CODES HERE ARE WORKING FINE...

    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) {

       //CODES HERE ARE WORKING FINE...

       lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
       lv.setAdapter(adapter);
       new Image().execute();//Executing Async Task For Image
    }
}

//AsyncTask For Image.
private class Image extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONArray> {

        //CODES HERE ARE WORKING FINE...

    protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray result) {
            String img;
            ImageView imv;
            l = result.length();
            JSONObject jsonObject;
            for (int i = 0; i < l; i++) {
                try {
                    jsonObject = result.getJSONObject(i);
                    img = "\n" + jsonObject.getString("image1") + "\n";
                    rawImage=Base64.decode(img, Base64.DEFAULT);
                    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(rawImage, 0, rawImage.length);

                    imv=adapter.getItem(i).imageview; //Getting null in imv
                    imv.setImageBitmap(bmp); //Thus this creates null pointer exception

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: please show your adapter code

Comment: @PhanVănLinh : Have added the adapter code.

Comment: Put the code for ab class also

Comment: @jaibatrik : ab class code added.

Comment: You're referencing `image1` in `imv=adapter.getItem(i).image1;` and your `ab` class definition defines it as `imageview`.  Is this a typo?

Comment: @AndrewSenner : Oh! Sry, yes it was a typo here. I have imageview on both places. Have edited the code.

Comment: Okay, so, then if that's not the issue, then R.id.image1 isn't being found in your XML layout.  Can you post the xml of the value `layoutResourceId`, Whatever xml file you're using for the adapter view

Comment: @AndrewSenner : Have added the layout code.

Comment: @RahulKumar Show me the code for `Image()`'s `doInBackground()` method.  This code doesn't look like it has any issues syntactically.  So I don't think the error is in anything you've posted so far.

Comment: @AndrewSenner : Have added the code for Image()'s doInBackground method.

Answer (score 1):

I got it finally!
Instead of:

```
imv=adapter.getItem(i).imageview;
```

The code has to be:

```
imv = (ImageView) lv.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.image1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use a separate library for downloading the images such as Piccasso or UniversalImageLoader.

Comment: My images are coming directly from the database not from the server. Piccasso needs url i.e. image should be on the server. Downloading the images is not the issue for me. I am not getting the ImageView where I need to put the images.

Comment: Hi Rahul, I thought you were doing a separate download for the image, sorry.
So, if you have them in a database, then can't you load them in the abAdapter?

Comment: When I add the texts and image together to the adapter it works but it makes the UI blank till the image gets fetched as it takes some time.
That's why I am fetching the texts and images separately and need to update the adapter after getting the image. But to do so I need to get the ImageView which is inside the adapter and in doing so I am getting null in return.

Comment: Hi Rahul,

Do you mean that the UI freezes otherwise?

Comment: No, it remains blank for while waiting for the adapter to populate it.